# Use Object Tag with JWPlayer and HLS

Tags: html, flash, object, jwplayer, osmf

I have jwplayer set up with an hls stream, it works fine.

I need to implement this on a page using the  tag however.  I cannot find documentation to support using JWPlayer as object for use with HLS streams. All combinations of variables I use seem to fail.

I'm willing to use another OSMF based player if it could be easier to use object and an hls stream.

Thanks if you can help. :)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't embed JW Player 6 with an <object> tag, under any circumstances.

Comment: Indeed, you need to use jwplayer.js to embed JW6.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. What about JW5 then? ...Or will I run into issues with hls?

Comment: No HLS support at all in JW Player 5. On top of that, all support for JW5 comes to an end on July 1.

Comment: Thanks MisterNeutron.

Comment: Thanks MisterNeutron.  Is it taboo to ask why JW6 can't support different embed methods, or why JW5 could never support HLS, "officially"? Is this just lack of concern of these issues by Longtail or programming challenge? It seems though your implying JW5 may work with <object> so perhaps I can use an hls fix for JW5 provided by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting my comments as the answer, for posterity.)

In JW Player 6, you must use the jwplayer.js script to embed the video. You can't use an object tag (or a video tag, for that matter).

JW Player 5 allowed the use of the object tag, but has no HLS support. In addition, all support for JW Player 5 ends on July 1, 2014.

Comment: Thanks MisterNeutron.  Hopefully I can find a more versatile player.   Anwser accepted. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Gives me a reason not to implement it.

Comment: What a strange attitude. You can't use an <object> or <video> tag in JW6 BECAUSE YOU DON'T NEED TO. The script takes care of all of that for you.